# Google Calendar Event Insert HTTP message format?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Google provides the HTTP message format for all the Oauth messages but nothing when it comes to the Calendar's API.

I suspect they want you to use one of their libraries -- but I don't use any of the languages associated with their libraries.

I'm using C++ and forming my own HTTP headers and message content.

Can anyone provide a standard HTTP format for Calendar-event-insert?

I know it must be in JSON construction.

The data I want to send is:

Calendar ID will be "primary"

Summary

Description

Start time

End Time

Based on oauth messages - I'm assuming the message may also have to contain:

ClientID

AccessToken

Scope

redirect_uri

I am looking for correct "Key" strings(case sensitive) and format.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all your self. The doucmentation is all there

## Calendar [event.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

If all you want to do is see the HTTP request that is made by the api you can use If you use the [event.Insert try me](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22end%22%3A%7B%22date%22%3A%222020-01-01%22%7D%2C%22start%22%3A%7B%22date%22%3A%222020-01-01%22%7D%2C%22description%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22summary%22%3A%22test%22%7D%7D=) You can see the request it builds and test that its working

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "end": {
    "date": "2020-01-01"
  },
  "start": {
    "date": "2020-01-01"
  },
  "description": "test",
  "summary": "test"
}
```

With a post body of [events.resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource)

## oauth

If you have your own C++ oauth library you can probably use that to get an access token.  Once you have the access token you simply need to add a Authorization header to the post request above with a bearer token of the access token.

Sorry i cant help much with the code for c++ but i made my own library for .net 3.5 because it was not supported by googles .net client library, so i can tell you that its doable you just have to do it all yourself.

## Google c++ library

There is a c++ library its just deprecated but that doesn't mean you cant dig around in their code for a bit of help in doing this [Google apis cpp client](https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client)